# Enable "Tab to search" in a website

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opensearch

I am looking for a way to enable Google Chrome's "Tab to search" feature on my website, does anyone have experience with this?

Google did not supply sufficient information for me and I am guessing this community is faster.

Much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to serve an opensearch xml, and link to it in your `<head>` tag. See the specs here:

https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch

And a user friendly description here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch